# get data from date between using like

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i am a beginner of the php. trying to do some search function in my project. the admin want to search based on the customer id,phone number, from date and to date. The admin want to search the data individually and also the combination of the search inputs. 
i want to know the following things.

1. How to fetch the data using multiple AND OR conditions.
2. My date fields are having the date and time combination i have to
   search the  date only.

Please help me to know how to do this. Thank you..

Comment: for multiple AND/OR you can use parentheses and for date search use `DATE(fieldname)`...you can share your table structure and expected output

Comment: i Have more than 10 fields in the table. but i have to search and get the combination of 4 fields like phone number, user_id, from_date, and also to_date. i entered the date fields using the date and time combination, so i  don't know how to get the date only.

Comment: The DATE function will extract the date part of a datetime field, so you can check that. But it means MySQL executing a function on each field, hence it might be quicker when checking a date range to use a time of 00:00:00 on the start date and 23:59:29 on the end date as this will allow an index to be used easily - eg , _WHERE some_date BETWEEN '2015-10-20 00:00:00' AND '2015-10-25 23:59:59'_

Comment: $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recharge_req WHERE (recharge_by='".$uid."' OR mobile='".$mobile."') OR (transid='".$reqid."' OR receive_datetime like '%$fdate%')"); ...The Query is execute but i have a problem in date only. I am using the date picker

Answer (score 0):

**With `AND`**

```
SELECT DATE(date1)
FORM table
WHERE date1 = user_date
AND date2 = user_date2
```

this will only return data when **both conditions** are TRUE

**With `OR`**

```
SELECT DATE(date2)
FORM table
WHERE date1 = user_date
OR date2 = user_date2
```

this will only return data when **one of the condition** get TRUE

---

After receive data use `strtotime`

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime(''));
```

---

**EDIT 01**

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE (date1 BETWEEN '2010-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2010-09-29 10:15:55');
```

---

**EDIT 02**

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recharge_req WHERE (recharge_by='$uid' OR mobile='$mobile') OR (transid='$reqid' OR receive_datetime like '%$fdate%')");
```

Comment: @raveenanigam thanx for EDIT

Comment: Hi abdulla i am having the date and time combination in the date fields. but i want to search the date only. and also i have to fetch the combination  of search fields

Comment: i want to fetch the date between

Comment: i am passing the value by using date picker but in my database date fields with date time format .

Comment: $uid = $_GET['uid'];
 $mobile = $_GET['mob'];
 $reqid = $_GET['reqid'];
 $fdate = $_GET['fdate'];
 $tdate = $_GET['tdate'];
 
 
 $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recharge_req WHERE (recharge_by='".$uid."' OR mobile='".$mobile."') OR (transid='".$reqid."' OR receive_datetime like '%$fdate%')");     this is my query i pass my date value in fdate and tdate my values are date format but in my database values are date time format

Comment: its ok.You will get output. first try this then come up with again

Comment: $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recharge_req WHERE (recharge_by='".$uid."' OR mobile='".$mobile."') OR (transid='".$reqid."' OR receive_datetime between '$fdate' AND '$tdate')"); I use this i didn't get result ,  user only selected date and search so i pass that value and get get result

Comment: $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recharge_req WHERE (recharge_by='$uid' OR mobile='$mobile') OR (transid='$reqid' OR receive_datetime between '$fdate' AND '$tdate')");    I don't get result on this query also

Comment: Can you post the actual query with the values in it please?

Comment: $uid = $_GET['uid'];
 $mobile = $_GET['mob'];
 $reqid = $_GET['reqid'];
 $fdate = $_GET['fdate'];
 $tdate = $_GET['tdate'];
 
 
 $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recharge_req WHERE (recharge_by='$uid' OR mobile='$mobile') OR (transid='$reqid' OR receive_datetime between '$fdate' AND '$tdate')");
 in my database receive_datetime values is like this 2015-09-23 03:31:28 but i Pass the value like 2015-09-23 in $fdate and $tdate .

Comment: Can you echo out the actual statement (with the values in place) that is not finding anything but which should be?

Comment: $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recharge_req WHERE (recharge_by='d1100' OR mobile='9597896676') OR (transid='5d6ada234' OR receive_datetime between '2015-09-23' AND '2015-09-23')");


( receive_datetime  values in database '2015-09-23 03:11:18')

Comment: i didn't get values for receive_date time because i pass only date to get result but in my database values are with date and time format how can i get that

Comment: i didn't get result for receive_datetime  ( receive_datetime values in database  '2015-09-23 03:11:18')  .... but i will pass to get that 2015-09-23  like this not with time

Comment: i want get result receive_datetime with date only not with time

Comment: after decive your value `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('$receive_datetime'));` use this this will render date only

Comment: i want to know how to search date_time values by date only

Comment: $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recharge_req WHERE (recharge_by='$uid' OR mobile='$mobile') OR (transid='$reqid' OR receive_datetime between '$fdate 00:00:00' AND '$tdate 23:59:59')"); I Get result on this query

Comment: how you pass this data `'$fdate 00:00:00'` show me variable

Comment: am passing date from date picker so i dont get time on that .. i want result between particular date_time so i pass 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 after my date values

Comment: The 00:00:00 is just a dummy time for the very start of the day, and 23:59:59 is a dummy time for the very end of the day. Adding these dummy times to the start and end dates will work and is probably the quickest way to find the rows with a date/time within the date range (assuming there is an index on the datetime field).